# mcrypt_decrypt does not always return correct text

Tags: php, encryption

This is my code:

```
class Security  {

    public function __construct($textkey) {
        $this->securekey = hash('sha256',$textkey,TRUE);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32);
    }

    // holds properties for encrpyting  
    private $securekey, $iv;

    /*
     * encrypting data 
     *
     * @param $data the value to be encrypted 
     * @return string the encrypted data 
     */
    public function encryptUrlData($input) {
        $url = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv));
        return urlencode($url);
    }

    /*
     * encrypting data 
     *
     * @param $data the value to be encrypted 
     * @return string the encrypted data 
     */
    public function decryptUrlData($input) {
        $input = urldecode($input);
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv));
    }
```

I am encrypting id's , so basically the values i encrypt are only digits. 
For example: an id of value "3" will be decrypted successfully while "1" is not decrypted successfully.

Comment: Every time you do `new Security('key')`, you will generate a new IV.  That IV is needed to decrypt the data.  Without it you cannot decrypt (it's also suggested that it be different for each piece of data).  You should have `encryptUrlData` create (and return) the IV, and then you should pass the encrypted data and its respective IV to `decryptUrlData`.

Comment: Thank for the comment . I am actually doing that. I am passing the property of this class(which is $iv) to the function "decryptUrlData". Actually I solve it already. I removed urldecode in the "decryptUrlData" function and VOILA! It magically works. Why do you you think urldecode solves it ? I really dont get it because i urlencode the data in the "encryptUrlData" function. Thanks

Comment: It *looks* to me like you already URL decode when receiving the `$input`, before you use it in the `decryptUrlData` method. Note that ECB mode *does not use an IV*. Also note that ECB mode is insecure, and note that you are using Rijndael with a block size of 256 bit, which is *not* AES. @RocketHazmat this may be of interest to you as it invalidates your suggestion about the IV.

Comment: hmmm. I did not use URL decode before using `decryptUrlData` method.
.. Can you help with a more secure way of this mycrypt? I'm only a student and im somewhat new to PHP. Thanks .

Comment: Please use @owlstead to make sure I read comments directed to me. As for a better example, look at the [sample code within the `mcrypt_encrypt` API](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) which I (re-)wrote.